# Javascript library for timeline chart creation

Tags: library, javascript

I would like to create a HTML tool which provides a timeline analysis of a trace log. Essentially I will be generating events (each of which have an associated start/end time and some payload data), and would like to visually be able to view the events and their associated data. Essentially the events will have a start time, an end time (or duration), and a payload. These events simply come from a log file.

The time range for these events will be on a millisecond and second basis, so I need a framework that can handle providing second/ms time slices.

Ideally it would look and function a lot like [Chrome's timeline tool](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/timeline-tool), which shows events, their durations, and their payloads upon inspection. Even the memory analysis aspect would be useful. Ideally I would also get to customize the look and feel of the timeline, but that is not a necessary requirement.

Are there any Javascript libraries that can help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out, I was able to adapt [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com)’ [column range](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/columnrange) chart to fit my use case. It allowed me to specify a number as the range at the bottom (which I can simply use as my milliseconds).

Comment: By the way, for Java programmers, HighCharts functionality is available as [Vaadin Charts](https://vaadin.com/charts) for use within the [Vaadin framework](https://vaadin.com/framework).